# Amazon ip can not connect with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-ec2

Using amazon ec2 service get the error `This site can’t be reached`.

> unexpectedly closed the connection. Try: Checking the connection
>   Checking the proxy and the firewall Running Windows Network
>   Diagnostics

Comment: any code etc? Always put your code...

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS TCP connection uses port 443. Ensure you have opened this port (443) for the security group associated with your ec2 instance